# Avoid autoplay in iFrame embedded video

Tags: html, iframe, video, embed, autoplay

I'm using the tag `<iframe>` to embed [this video](http://www.retromallorca.com/archivos/2014/trailer-retromallorca-2014.mp4) to my website, and I can't avoid the autoplay function, I've tried adding `&autoplay=0` to the url, `autoplay='false'` to the config, etc, but I can't avoid it.

Here's my html:

```
  <iframe src='http://www.retromallorca.com/archivos/2014/trailer-retromallorca-2014.mp4' width='600' height='350' frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you show us your html?